# AngularJS $window.open('url', '_blank') directs to currentpath+url instead of url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to open a new tab with a specific url.

When i enter

```
$window.open('www.example.com', '_blank')
```

i do get a new tab, just like i wanted but instead of going to: www.example.com

im directed to: http://localhost:8080/www.example.com

It concatinates my input with my current address

How do i open a new tab with exactly the url i put in the input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `$window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank')` (that is, add `http://` so it's not interpreted as a relative URL)?

Comment: Had a similar problem in Angular, new window was blank and didn't hit any code, It was because I was building the URL with location.host without "http://" in front.  Thanks for helping me solve it.