# Open link in new tab without base url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to open a url on new tab. I am doing following:

```
$scope.portal.jdURL = 'www.google.com';

$scope.openURL = function()
 {

     if($scope.portal.jdURL != '')
     {
         window.open($scope.portal.jdURL, '_blank');
     }

 };
```

I want the result as:

**www.google.com**

but it opening url like following:

**http://localhost/trial01/www.google.com**

Comment: try this `$window.open('//google.com');`

Comment: have a look this ans. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31432423/4426282

Comment: It works. But user can enter url in any format. like www.google.com or simply google.com or https://www.google.com. it should work for any input.

Answer (score 1):

simply change

```
$scope.portal.jdURL = 'www.google.com';
```

to

```
$scope.portal.jdURL = 'http://www.google.com';
```